# How do you send an RichText Document as the body of an e-mail programatically using SmtpClient with .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, email, smtpclient

I am writing a WPF .net app to send an e-mail to several people.

I've got the program working so that it sends plain text e-mails using the code below:

```
  private void OnSendEmails(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("<mySMTPserver>", <somePort>))
     {
        smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<myusername>", "<mypassword");

        foreach (string address in Addresses)
        {
           try
           {
              Console.Out.WriteLine("Sending e-mail to:  {0}", address);
              smtpClient.Send(Sender, address, Subject, Body);
              Console.Out.WriteLine("Sent e-mail to:  {0}", address);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              Console.Out.WriteLine("Exception thrown while sending to :  {0}\r\n\r\n{1}", address, ex);
           }

           Console.Out.WriteLine("Sleeping");
           Thread.Sleep(Seconds * 1000);
           Console.Out.WriteLine("Done Sleeping");
        }
     }
  }
```

I would like to send several e-mails out to a select group of people to advertise an app that I wrote.  However, I want to send them something other than plain text.  I can populate a RichTextBox with the content I wish to send, however, I don't know how to send it since SmtpClient just takes a 'string' to represent the body of the e-mail.

So the question is, how do I send the RichTextBox.Document as the Body of my e-mail using .net and SmptClient?

The document itself will contain images, text, and some links that are associated with icons.

Comment: Now imagine receiving this on an iPad or Linux box. What will you see?

Comment: Pretty much a standard e-mail with a couple screenshots and a couple links to the AppStore.  Perhaps using icons for the links instead of the actual urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to create an object of type `MailMessage`:

```
var msg = new MailMessage(...);
```

then you can set this property:

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

and the message body will be rendered in HTML format.

I am not totally sure the RichTextBox would pass HTML or probably RTF which is slightly different, it could be you should convert RTF into HTML with an helper method before assigning the content to `msg.Body`.